# Trigonometry Problem - Distance between surveyors

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Sally and Marko are two surveyors that have become separated out in the wilderness. Sally is due east of Marko. Marko radios Sally "The distance from me to the top of Kitt's Peak is 7.8km. It is at an angle of elevation of 32 degrees". Sally radios back "I am 6.5km from the top of the peak". Calculate all possible distances Marko must hike due east in order to reach Sally. Round to the nearest tenth of a kilometer.

I have got an answer of 1.6km by creating a right triangle and using SOH-CAH-TOA but I think I'm wrong because I believe the Law of Sine has to be used, but I do not know how to apply it to this question. Any help is appreciated!

MY WORK: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWgug.jpg

Comment: Could you please add what you have done? Someone could check over your work for you.

Comment: I added the link to the imgur sorry. https://imgur.com/a/lfC1frF

Comment: You have found one solution.  To find the other, you need to consider the possibility that Sally is on the opposite side of the mountain from Marko.

Comment: I believe I've found the other solution, I posted it in this new link. https://imgur.com/a/vQlDyQ5

Comment: Yes, your revised solution is correct.  When you pose a question here, you should type your work since links to images can get broken, images cannot be searched, and users who rely on screen readers may not be able to read your work.  For future reference, this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know I could do that. Thanks again!

Comment: I wonder what meaning have the words "angle of elevation" here...

Comment: @user - angle of elevation is the angle between a point and the horizontal plane, positive for points above the plane, negative for those below. In this case the angle between the surveyor's line-of-sight to Kitt's peak and the true horizon.

Comment: @PaulSinclair This is the usual definition. But in the given solution it seems to be the angle between the line-of-sight and the direction to the east.

Comment: @user - N. F. Taussig was being a little incautious in their wording. There are not two solutions here, but a continuum - a full interval of solutions. However, the two extremes of that interval both occur when Kitt's peak is due east of Marko. (Although this interprets "distance Marko has to hike" as being "straight-line distance from Marko to Sally". Without that inpretation, the problem is unsolvable, since we do not know much about what ups and downs Marko must navigate between them.)

Comment: Actually, without making any assumptions about the shape of the terrain around the peak, she could be anywhere from $7.8-6.5 = 1.3$ km to $7.8 + 6.5 = 14.3$ km away from him.

Comment: @PaulSinclair True, but in that case there is no trigonometry involved (and the $32$ degrees is useless information). The question is poorly phrased (in my opinion), but the usual guess-the-examiner's-intent game points toward the interpretation that Sally is due east of Marko at the same elevation, leading to a continuum of answers with N.F. Taussig's two solutions at the extreme ends of the solution set.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the person who wrote this question meant for you to assume that Sally and Marko are at the same elevation above sea level, that is, at the same altitude above sea level.

This is only a guess, not a fact stated in the problem, because the term "due east" gives only part of the direction to another point on, above, or below the Earth. The other component of the direction is the angle of elevation. For example, it is possible (although not given) in the statement of the problem that Kitt's Peak is due east of Marko, but we know Kitt's Peak is not at the same elevation above sea level as Marko.

So this is a poorly worded problem that invites us to play a guess-what-the-test-maker-was-thinking game.

I make my guess because without such an assumption, all you really know is that Sally is somewhere in three-dimensional space $6.5$ km from a point that is $7.8$ km from Marko. (You also know the slope of the line from Marko to that point, but since Sally could in principle be looking down onto Kitt's Peak from some higher peak, the slope of one line does not help you at all.)

If you assume that Sally and Marko are at the same elevation above sea level,
then you can work out the sides of a right triangle whose hypotenuse is the line of sight from Marko to Kitt's Peak; one leg is a horizontal line segment of length $7.8 \cos(32^\circ)$ and the other leg is a vertical line segment of length $7.8 \sin(32^\circ),$ as you worked out.

Since Sally is at the same elevation as Marko, the right triangle consisting of one horizontal leg, one vertical leg, and a hypotenuse from her position to Kitt's Peak has the same height as Marko's triangle.
You can use the Pythagorean Theorem to find the length of the horizontal leg.

You also know that the horizontal legs of the two right triangles meet at a point directly underneath Kitt's Peak. Those two legs, and the horizontal line between Marko and Sally, form a third triangle, not necessarily a right triangle (possibly even a degenerate triangle).
You will have worked out two sides of that triangle using the methods shown in your working of the question.
Since the question says nothing about the bearing from anyone to Kitt's Peak,
all you can conclude about the third side is that it must make a triangle of some kind with the other two sides.
That gives you a range of possible answers.

---

There is still another gaping hole in the presumed logic of the question, which is the assumption that Marko can hike to Sally's position along a perfectly straight line. That's an obviously unrealistic assumption.
So we may have a lower bound on the distance but not an upper bound.
But again we play guess-what-they-meant and conclude that the answer is supposed to assume travel in a straight line.